# quadratic Sum of N nummbers: implementation in C

Tags: c, math

As you can read in the header it is about a rather simple topic. But I encountered something very odd while implementing possible different ways to get a quadratic sum of N numbers.

I implemented three different versions:

- Quadratic Gauß sum (func: quadratGauss(int n) )
- Iterative (func: quadratIterativeClassic(int n) )
- Iterative via Bitoperation (func: quadratIterativeBitoperation(int n) )

All three functions have returned the same result as expected from the given Input. The Big question now is. How was it possible for the third function to work proper? The Code looks like this:

```
void quadratGauss(int n){

    printf("+quadratGauss: \n");
    int result = ((n*(n+1))*(2*n+1))/2;
    printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}

void quadratIterativClassic(int n){

    int result;
    printf("+quadratIterativClassic: \n");
    for(int i;i<=n;i++)
        result += i * i;
    printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}

void quadratIterativeBitOperation(int n){

    int result;
    printf("+quadratIterativeBitOperation: \n");

    for(int i;i<=n;i++)
        result += i^2;

    printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}
```

As you see I use the XOR operator. I originally wanted to use the shift-operator "<<" but i tried others as well. what where stunning when i tried the XOR operator: the result was still the same as before and the same as the other two functions. I thought this was not possible because **the XOR is not an operator for the power-operation** because C does not contain such an operator but still i got eventually the right result.

I tested the functions with different numbers of different "sizes". Nothing odd in the result of each function.

I've got no clue why. But there must be an explanation, doesn't it?
If you have one, I would appreciate alot the effort of writing down a possible reason, why you can implement this with the XOR operator.

here the whole main file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>

#define N 5000



void sumGauss(int n)
{
printf("+sumGauss: \n");
int result = (n*(n+1)/2);
printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);
}

void sumClassic(int n)
{
printf("+sumClassic: \n");
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    result += i;
printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);
}

void quadratGauss(int n){

printf("+quadratGauss: \n");
int result = ((n*(n+1))*(2*n+1))/2;
printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}

void quadratIterativeBitOperation(int n){

int result;
printf("+quadratIterativeBitOperation: \n");
for(int i;i<=n;i++)
    result += i^2;
printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}

void quadratIterativClassic(int n){

int result;
printf("+quadratIterativClassic: \n");
for(int i;i<=n;i++)
    result += i * i;
printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

}

void unevenSum(int n)
{
printf("+unevenSum: \n");
int uneven = 0;
int i=0;
for(i=1;i<= n;i+=2) {
    uneven += i;
}

printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",uneven*2);


}

void unevenSumModulo(int n)
{
printf("+unevenSumModulo: \n");
int result=0;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    if( (i%1) == 0)
        result += i;
}

printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);


}

void unevenSumNico(int n)
{
printf("+unevenSumNico: \n");
int odd = 0;
int i=0;
for(i=1;i<= n;i++) {
    odd += ((2*i)-1)/2;
}

printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",odd);


}

void evenSum(int n)
{
printf("+evenSum: \n");
int result=0;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    if( (i%2) == 0)
        result += i;
}

printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);


}

void Zins(float Kapital,int years)
{
printf("Zinstabelle fuer Grundkaptial %.2f Euro\n",Kapital);
printf("Kapitalstand zum Jahresende\n");
int i=0;
float K = Kapital;
for(int i =1;i<years+1;i++)
{

    K = K *(1.f + 0.05f);
    printf("Jahr: %2d         Kapital: %.2f Euro\n",i,K);

}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

sumGauss(N);
sumClassic(N);

quadratGauss(N);
quadratIterativeBitOperation(N);
quadratIterativClassic(N);

unevenSum(N);
unevenSumNico(N);
unevenSumModulo(N);

evenSum(N);
Zins(N);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `i` or `result` in either iterative function, so I assume that the initial value of `i` is greater than `n`, the loop doesn't run, and the result is unchanged from the first call to `quadratGauss`. In other words, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: okay that is definitly something i did wrong, but how is it possible to get still the same values? i thought as soon i leave a function the stack of that function disappears into the nirvana?

Comment: The stack is "freed" meaning the stack pointer is set to the value before the function was executed. The next function is "overwriting" the old stack values when it is called. Or, when you are not initializing variables, it might just take whatever is written in that specific address of the stack (which in your case could be the values from the previous function)

Comment: This apparently was what happened. thanks alot for the explanation :D

Comment: @ExOfDe To understand exactly what your code is doing, you need to take a look at the assembly code. You can do that by compiling with `-S`. Or compile normally and look at the assembly with the debugger. There are a lot of factors that determine what the code will do in these cases (e.g. processor type, [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), optimization level, etc.) so trying to explain undefined behavior is generally a wasted effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would only be true for `n = 0`. Rest assured that you cannot implement squaring using just the XOR operator, even for integral types.

The behaviour of your code is currently *undefined*, as you don't initialise either `i`, or `result`. I suspect that your loop does not run at all and by the *most amazing coincidence*, `result` occupies the same memory in the subsequent functions as it does in the Guassian function. But don't ever *rely* on that behaviour. Other compilers might simply attempt to eat your cat.

Comment: Okay that's true. Thanks a lot. But one question then remains: why got i still the same result? And why did this most amazing coincidence happend frequently?

Comment: crazy.... and i could not get my head around why that happend XD. just for got to initialise...

Comment: Similarly in `quadratIterativClassic` the local variable `int result;` is uninitialised therefore UB. Please turn on compiler warnings - it should have told you!

Comment: Analysing undefined behaviour is rather like trying to nail jelly to the wall. What JonnyMopp is saying is *probably* what is happening, but don't ever rely on that. Note that a *stack* is an *implementation* concept, not a *language* concept.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am aware of that fact that the stack is not a language concept, but thanks for pointing out it :D

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
   int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int i=0,n1;
     scanf("%d",&n1);

void quadratGauss(int n){
 printf("+quadratGauss: \n");
  int result = ((n*(n+1))*(2*n+1))/6;   // you made here mistake take 2 insted of 6.
  printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);
 }

void quadratIterativClassic(int n){

  int result=0;
   printf("+quadratIterativClassic: \n");
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       result += i * i;
  printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);
 }

void quadratIterativeBitOperation(int n){
   int result=0;
   printf("+quadratIterativeBitOperation: \n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)

    result += pow(i,2);  //This is power fun to add series of quadrat

    printf("Result: %d\n----------------\n",result);

  }
   //call the fun.
  quadratGauss(n1);
  quadratIterativClassic(n1);
  quadratIterativeBitOperation(n1);

  return 0; 
 }
```

:) Want to more about http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: yeah, that was a typo, but after getting so amazed that XOR would produce the same result i just didn't check the correctness of my math formular. but thanks pointing it out. and yeah there is an function  math.h. but the task was not to use it... to simple

Answer (score 0):

First, its /6, not /2. See that quadratGauss is always 3 times the quadratIterativClassic. And I got completely different results for quadratIterativeBitOperation

```
n = 4
+quadratGauss: 
Result: 90
----------------
+quadratIterativClassic: 
Result: 30
----------------
+quadratIterativeBitOperation: 
Result: 12
----------------
n = 5
+quadratGauss: 
Result: 165
----------------
+quadratIterativClassic: 
Result: 55
----------------
+quadratIterativeBitOperation: 
Result: 19
----------------
n = 6
+quadratGauss: 
Result: 273
----------------
+quadratIterativClassic: 
Result: 91
----------------
+quadratIterativeBitOperation: 
Result: 23
```

I think it your compiler must have ^ set as exponent instead of XOR

Comment: I do not think there is such an option for GCC neither for C or C++ or any other language. Except for languages who could overwrite operators which i did not